# Difference between Dueling DQN and Double DQN?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, dqn, deep-learning

I have read some articles, but still can not figure out the difference between the Dueling DQN and Double DQN? What exactly is the difference between them? Also, Does Dueling DQN need to be built on top of a Double DQN? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

They are separate techniques.
Double uses two networks to avoid over optimistic q-values.
Dueling separates the estimator using two new streams, value and advantage. The two streams are then aggregated.